# Buttons not displaying properly after upgrade to ADT 20 (Helios, Mac)

Tags: android, android-layout, adt

Just updated to ADT 20 and none of the buttons in my layouts are displaying properly in the editor.

**Anyone else having the problem?**

Basically the buttons display with no background (no default grey button background as they used to). So if I add a new button to the layout it just shows as text only (on top of the window background). Also all existing buttons in my layouts do not display properly.

During install of ADT 20 there were these issues (showed in a dialog box):
!MESSAGE Marker id 345609 not found.
!MESSAGE Marker id 345610 not found.
!MESSAGE Marker id 345611 not found.

Not sure if those are relevant or not.

Tried uninstalling/re-installing ADT 20 to no avail, same problem with the buttons (but no dialog box errors on second install).

Anyone know how to make the backgrounds of my buttons show up again?

Comment: I haven't upgraded yet (due to concerns about problems) but I would guess that those are the button background IDs? Have you checked the android.jar library (I assume you are using eclipse, you can just use the package explorer view) to see if they are still present? For me they are under `android.jar/res.drawable/btn.default` and related. (default-small, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the API used by the layouts to anything but API 9 :Android 2.3.1 which is what they were set to.

In ADT 20 there is a green Android icon on upper right of graphical editor which lets you choose the API level to be used in the graphical editor.

Changing to API 10 or anything higher fixed the problems. So that works for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387606/adt-20-graphical-layout-editor/11667741#11667741) - in particular, 2.3.1 is obsolete and doesn't look like it will be updated to solve this issue.