# ADT 20 Graphical Layout Editor

Tags: android, adt

I recently updated my ADT to version 20.something. Since then, the Graphical Layout Editor is acting strange, while using API Level 3.

Instead of showing buttons it is only displaying some kind of label.

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipZmK.jpg

If I change the Project Build Target to API Level 7 everything is working fine. But we're planning on using the lowest possible API Level for our project, so this is not really a valid solution to the problem.

Of course I've read most of the older topics covering a similar problem, but couldn't find any suitable information.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Best regards, sf

Comment: How does it run on the emulator or on device?

Comment: It's running fine in the emulator. Did not yet test on a real device, but I think it'll run there too.

Comment: It's running fine on a real device too, just checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WYSIWYG editor has only recently been made available.

I wouldn't worry too much about how things are displayed in the layout editor as it has quite a few bugs still.

If it works well in your emulator and on device, then the most reasonable explanation is that the layout editor is wrong. :)

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you. I was wondering if it was my "fault". I recently downgraded from Java 7 to 6, because some Eclipse Plugins still don't like Java 7 too much, and thought it could be some kind of "hiccup" because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem when there were outstanding revisions of the APIs to download, e.g. I had the Android 2.2 API rev 2 installed, but rev 3 was available. Downloading the updates appeared to fix the issue.

I note that when changing the layout editor to show renderings for 2.0 or 2.3.1, it is still broken, but these platforms are obsolete so no surprise there. I suspect something changed and the updates are required to give compatibility in the layout view.